# Using StorIO with AndroidX and Jetifier

Tags: android, androidx, storio, android-jetifier

We are converting one of our project to AndroidX and the jetifier seems to choke on the `@NonNull` annotation in the generated resolver (e.g., `mapFromCursor(@NonNull ...)`

When compiling we have `Cannot find symbol` on the `NonNull` symbol. This is probably because the jetifier did not convert `com.android.support:support-annotations` into `androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1`.

I did put the following to my `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Anyone else ran into this as well?